# prove that $U(\frac{1}{f},P)-L(\frac{1}{f},P)\leq \frac{1}{c^2}(U(f,P)-L(f,P))$ where $c$ is a lower bound for $f$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded below by $c>0$, $U$  denote the upper sum and $L$ the lower sum.
Prove that
$$U(\frac{1}{f},P)-L(\frac{1}{f},P)\leq \frac{1}{c^2}(U(f,P)-L(f,P))$$
for any partition $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
For any $x,y$,

$$ \left|\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{f(y)}\right| =  \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|f(x)f(y)|} 
 \leq \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{c^2}$$

You should be able to continue now.

Comment: This would then imply $M_i(1/f)-m_i(1/f)\leq 1/c^2(M_i(f)-m_i(f))$, right? (M_i being the $\sup$ on an interval and $m_i$ the $\inf$)

Comment: Exactly. That's correct.